# Replacing a key by its value in a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
my_dict = {"a":1, "e":2, "i":3, ...}
```

And I also have a list which consists of different graphemes:

```
my_list = ["t", "a", "b", "l", "e", ...]
```

What I want to do is iterate over each of the graphemes in my list and, if the grapheme is part of the dictionary, then replace it by its value.

I tried using `my_dict.get()`, though it requires an argument (which corresponds to a given value). Since I don't know what the exact value will be, for it will be changing depending on the grapheme that the function is iterating over, what could I do to get my desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by being part of dictionary, is it being its key or value?

Comment: `my_dict.get(), though it requires an argument (which corresponds to a given value)`. No, that's not true. The argument is a **key**, not a value.

Comment: @Looioe if the grapheme is the key. So, in this case, all "a" should be replaced by "1", and so on

Comment: `my_dict.get()` takes a **key**, and a default value to return when the key is missing. In your case, both the key *and* that default value to return is the grapheme *itself*. So `my_dict.get('a', 'a')` returns `1`, but `my_dict.get('t', 't')` returns `'t'`. Use `[my_dict.get(grapheme, grapheme) for grapheme in my_list]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
result = [my_dict.get(grapheme, grapheme) for grapheme in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list-comprehension with `dict.get()` which takes two parameters: key and a default value (optional).

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> `get(key[, default])`: 
>   Returns the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
>   If default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method
>   never raises a `KeyError`.

```
my_dict = {"a": 1, "e": 2, "i": 3}
my_list = ["t", "a", "b", "l", "e"]

print([my_dict.get(x, x) for x in my_list])
# ['t', 1, 'b', 'l', 2]
```